# Creating new folders on Outlook 2011

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-interface, microsoft-outlook-2011

I can not seem to find how to create new folders in Outlook.  There are different ways to create subfolders within an already existing folder but I can't create new folders from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean by "from scratch"?

Answer (score 2):

You can add folders on an Account Level, as well as folders within folders in an account.

I've included screen shots on how to add a folder to an account.

[image: AccountLevelFolderAdd]
[image: Adding the new folder]